# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tagName')

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why it's returning error with tagName. is subLabel wrong?

```
for (var ind = 0; ind < target.length; ind++)
    {
        var target = target[ind]
        for (var ind; ind < target.childNodes.length; ind++);
        {
            const subLabel = target.childNodes[ind];
            if (subLabel.tagName == "SPAN" || subLabel.tagName == "LI") //error line
            {
                //do something with label
            }
            typeDisplay(subLabel);
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `var ind` twice. Use `let` instead. Read [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Scope%20in%20JavaScript%20refers%20to,declared%20inside%20of%20a%20block)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable name in both inner and outer for loop (ie. `var ind`).

what you can do here is either change the variable name in the inner loop or change the variable name in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's common for nested loops, to use a different loop variable, such as while the outer loop uses `var i=0;` the inner loop uses `var j=0;`.

The posted code, the 2nd `var ind` is duplicated, because it shares the same variable scope of the 1st `var`.